# c# async runs single threaded?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I was reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx.
Example code:

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    // You need to add a reference to System.Net.Http to declare client.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await the 
    // task you'll get a string (urlContents).
    Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

    // You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
    DoIndependentWork();

    // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync. 
    //  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete. 
    //  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync. 
    //  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete.  
    //  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask. 
    string urlContents = await getStringTask;

    // The return statement specifies an integer result. 
    // Any methods that are awaiting AccessTheWebAsync retrieve the length value. 
    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

The page also says:

> The async and await keywords don't cause additional threads to be created. Async methods don't require multithreading because an async method doesn't run on its own thread

Does this "no additional thread is created" applies within scope of the method marked as async?

I would imagine in order for both GetStringAsync and AccessTheWebAsync to be running at the same time (otherwise GetStringAsync will never finish as AccessTheWebAsync has control now), eventually GetStringAsync has to run on a different thread from AccessTheWebAsync's thread.

To me, writing async method is only useful at not adding more thread when the method it awaits is also async (which already use extra thread to do its own thing in parallel)

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the key to the power of `async`. `GetStringAsync` and other naturally-asynchronous operations *do not require a thread*. `GetStringAsync` just sends out the HTTP request and registers a callback to run when the server replies. There's no need for a thread just to wait for the server to respond.

In reality, the thread pool is used just a tiny bit. In the example above, the callback registered by `GetStringAsync` will execute on a thread pool thread, but all it does is notify `AccessTheWebAsync` that it can continue executing.

I have an [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) you may find helpful.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "naturally asynchronous operations do not require a thread"? How else can that work be processed? Are you talking about a single thread's time being split among tasks?

Comment: @VincePanuccio: It's a bit long to describe in a comment, but I have [a blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) that goes into detail.

Comment: I miss one thing though - how can `await` continue on the UI thread if the thread after executing my function (let's say, called on a `onClick`) has already moved on to process other events in the UI message loop (I mean the famous WinMain loop)? How and what mechanism suddenly interrupts the UI event loop and tells it to return to the code after `await`? Is there any article on that? I mean - there has to be some level where the most top level async functions (even `async Task main()`) are executed in synchronous manner to prevent the program from exiting immediately after launching the task?

Comment: @JustAMartin: As mentioned in my [async intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), by default `await` captures a context and uses that to resume execution, and this context is a `SynchronizationContext` for UI apps. There's more info on `SynchronizationContext` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext), but the gist is that when an `async` method resumes on the UI thread, it does so by dispatching a custom Win32 message to WinMain.

Comment: @JustAMartin: Console apps are completely different. `async Main` is in fact implemented by blocking on the `Task` returned from `Main`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks. "Custom Win32 message" - that is exactly the bit I miss. Maybe I'm using wrong keywords but somehow I can't find the exact message and the mechanism for the UI context switching for WinMain case. Of course, it's not important for everyday use of async/await but still, I'm really curious about how exactly does it work under the hood. This info is often missing from many articles about async - it is treated as a black box where the top level caller of the async chain has to be able to react to context switching requests, but it is not explained how exactly it does that.

Comment: @JustAMartin: It's not explained (or documented) because it's an implementation detail of the framework you're using. My knowledge comes from decompiling the BCL, but these days [WinForms](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/2ae45c66fdcb8e6aadf43288b7429f17f1fd0f49/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.cs) and [WPF](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/8bc1cb02609e549bf98aa64dc039b0c5b5debb8b/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/WindowsBase/System/Windows/Threading/DispatcherSynchronizationContext.cs) are both open-sourced.

Answer (score 2):

> I would imagine in order for both GetStringAsync and AccessTheWebAsync **to be running at the same time** ...

They don't run at the same time (at least not in the way you're thinking).  Now, if HttpClient.GetStringAsync itself

- started work on a different thread, then that code could be running at the same time, -or-
- Had an await (with ConfigureAwait(false)), then the remainder of the work in that method would be scheduled on to the Thread pool thread (and so that code could be running at the same time.

The point is that declaring a method as `async` and/or using `await`, doesn't cause the method that that you are authoring to be run on a separate thread (you would have to do that explicitly).

Note:
Without having the code (or documentation) of another asynchronous method, you don't really know how much of it is run synchronously.  It doesn't really start being asynchronous until that method does an `await` or explicitly starts work on another thread (usually by starting a new `Task`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread that is taken from the thread pool for the operation if that is necessary. In case of a console (not discussing the UI thread or IO threads) the current thread goes in the console and another thread is taken for the execution, and this new thread is the one that executes the remaining of the operation.

Answer (score -3):

What the author is saying here, is that simply using the async and await keywords somewhere does not cause the current method to run on a different thread. Let's investigate what happens in the code provided.

```
async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    // You need to add a reference to System.Net.Http to declare client.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await the 
    // task you'll get a string (urlContents).
    Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
```

Everything up to this point has executed in a single thread. At this point, the client.GetStringAsync call could spin off a new thread (although this is not guarenteed for any async method). It should be noted though that the GetStringAsync method essentially starts up on this current thread (such as actually making the call), but reading the response will execute in a different thread once it has returned. This is represented by it returning a Task object. The Task may represent an already completed bit of work, a currently executing secondary thread, or a unit of work that is simply scheduled to execute later.

```
DoIndependentWork();
```

This now executes on our primary thread, after the call has been queued (or possibly sent). Thus, this could be occuring while waiting for the request to be returned. Note that we are still on our primary thread.

```
 string urlContents = await getStringTask;
```

At this point, our thread returns. .NET will create a continuation function containing the remainder of the method (return urlContents.Length;) which will automatically be called for us once the getStringTask completes on it's own thread. At that point, a new thread will pick up the continuation.

Through all of this, the entirety of what we wrote in our async method, up to the await keyword, ran in a single thread. Sure, we called another method that could happen to spawn another thread, but there was nothing that we did to create another thread just by using the async/await keywords. The continuation at the end can be called possibly by a different thread, but after our initial function has actually returned (Which is why our function returns a Task object, to represent work that may not have yet completed when any calls to this function returns).

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. A `Task` object does not necessarily represent code; in particular, `GetStringAsync` will never spin up another thread to wait for the server.